# Notice: Undefined index: PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

Estoy corriendo un código en PHP y funciona totalmente! cumple con lo que pido, pero me arroja el siguiente error:

> Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\profile.php
>   on line 12

Lo que hice fue un perfil de un login que al momento de aceptarme el mail con el que se registro un usuario, muestre automaticamente su nombre, y lo hace perfectamente, pero me marca ese error, este es el código:

```
<?php
include('classes/DB.php');
include('login.php');
$email = "";
 if (isset($_GET['email'])){
    $name = isset($_GET['name']) ? $_GET['name'] : '';
    if(DB::query('SELECT name, email FROM registroalumnos WHERE email=:email', array(':email'=>$_GET['email']))){
              $email = DB::query('SELECT email FROM registroalumnos WHERE email=:email', array(':email'=>$_GET['email']))[0]['email'];
              $name = DB::query('SELECT name FROM registroalumnos', array(':name'=>$_GET['name']))[0]['name'];
    }else {
        die('Usuario no encontrado');
    }
 }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <title>Perfil</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Perfil de <?php echo $name;?></h1>



</body>
</html>
```

Ya verifiqué mucho el código y no sé por qué ocasiona eso.

Comment: Probablemente tienes nombre distinto en los atributos name de tu código html, por favor coloca el html para verificarlo.

Comment: Si lo que quieres es buscar el nombre de la persona basándote en el email no tienes que usar para nada el `_GET['name']`. Sólo necesitas el  primer SELECT, con el cual  encontrarás el nombre y el email. Aquí la cuestión es: ¿Cómo te devuelve `query` los datos? En base a eso podrás saber cómo recuperarlos. Puedes hacer lo siguiente: `$datos=DB::query('SELECT name, email FROM registroalumnos WHERE email=:email', array(':email'=>$_GET['email']));` y luego `var_dump($datos);` para ver cómo query devuelve los datos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Por lo que veo en el código:

```
$email = DB::query('SELECT email FROM registroalumnos WHERE email=:email', array(':email'=>$_GET['email']))[0]['email'];
$name = DB::query('SELECT name FROM registroalumnos', array(':name'=>$_GET['name']))[0]['name'];
```

Estás realizando una consulta con el email y luego con el name a la misma tabla, obviamente comparas únicamente si el email existe acá:

```
 if (isset($_GET['email'])){ ... }
```

Tu array `$_GET` no contiene el indice `'name'` y por ende te da ese warning.

La segunda consulta es redundante y en realidad no filtra nada, pues no está parametrizada.

Seguramente quisiste hacer lo siguiente:

```
$datos_usuario = DB::query('SELECT name, email FROM registroalumnos WHERE email=:email', array(':email'=>$_GET['email']));
//mostrar email y nombre
```

Comment: De hecho esa línea de código la tengo implementada pero como un if, al verificar que tengo el email correcto. Y esa segunda consulta es para llamar al nombre que esta en el email y poder imprimirlo en 
<h1>Perfil de <?php echo $name;?></h1>

Comment: Ok, no observé esa condición. Sin embargo obtener el nombre por separado es redundante como mencioné en mi comentario - pues la consulta se hace a la misma tabla.

Comment: Es que hice una doble consulta con la variable $name para que pueda almacenar y buscar el nombre según el email ingresado, y poder imprimir esa variable en "$name", porque si la ponía con "$email", me imprime el correo,,, por eso el <h1> que puse.

Comment: Tenías razón!!!, no había hecho bien la consulta y gracias a tu línea que me brindaste FUNCIONÓ!, te lo agrezco mucho, dure mucho tiempo en eso jaja.

Answer (score 5):

```
Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\profile.php on line 12
```

Según parece **name** no existe, no tiene pq ser que es nulo, puede que la variable esta simplemente vacía.

Tu código

```
$name = isset($_GET['name']) ? $_GET['name'] : '';
```

Prueba

```
$name = empty($_GET['name']) ? $_GET['name'] : '';
```

O puede ser que lo estes mandado con POST

```
$name = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : '';
```

Sin el HTML es dificil ver que pasa realmente

Comment: Disculpa la demora, ya no tuve oportunidad de revisar la pregunta, pero en base a tu respuesta, utilce con "empty" y "_POST" y me siguió marcando esa noticia, de igual manera ya edite la pregunta con mi HTML.

Answer (score 2):

Al juzgar por el error

```
Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\profile.php on line 12
```

Te esta indicando que `name` no existe en el arreglo `$_GET` debes verificar el atributo `name` de tu codigo html.

Si lo colocas editare la respuesta en base a tu codigo.

Comment: Esto es lo que tengo mi HTML

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
 <title>Perfil</title>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
 <h1>Perfil de <?php echo $name;?></h1>



</body>
</html>

en el h1 es donde imprimo el nombre, en base a la consulta del name.

Comment: Ya agregue a la pregunta mi HTML.

Comment: @AntonioAlejos lo que sucede es que no estas consultando correctamente el nombre, para no redundar te recomiendo leer la respuesta de james_bond que esta mas arriba ya que el da en el punto que te falta.

Comment: Claro, de hecho ahí tengo en mi SELECT la variable "name", lo malo es que aún así no me muestra el nombre del email ingresado.

Answer (score 1):

> Estoy corriendo un código en PHP y funciona totalmente! cumple con lo
>   que pido, pero me arroja el siguiente error: Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\profile.php on line 12

Ya que los demás colegas te han dado la respuesta correcta a tu pregunta sólo me queda aclararte que no es un **"error"** como mencionas en tu pregunta el mensaje arrojado por el **xampp**. Los **"notice"** funcionan más bien como una **"advertencia"** de que un proceso o parte de tu código no se está ejecutando de la "mejor manera" según las validaciones estándar que maneja el **xampp**.

En que se diferencian de un **error** común? Pues el **error** común detiene proceso y crea un fallo en tu aplicación, el **notice** sólo es una advertencia que sería prudente tomar en cuenta.

Siempre que el notice muestre **undefined index** quiere decir que alguna variable no fue declarada previa a su utilización y además al momento de utilizarla dicha variable está vacia. De allí el hecho de que **xampp** te informe mediante un **notice**. Eso es todo, Un Saludo!

Comment: Muchas gracias!, me sirvió mucho, solo que ya intente lo que los demás han dicho, pero sigue sin funcionarme, ya pegue el HTML a la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que si en el isset le preguntas si es igual a 0 o a "", te da igual utilizar get o post. Los dos son iguales, pero get muestra los datos en la caja de texto del navegador y en IE tiene una capacidad menor de caracteres.